# Apache Spark MLLib - Running KMeans with IDF-TF vectors - Java heap space

Tags: scala, apache-spark, out-of-memory, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying to run a KMeans on MLLib from a (large) collection of text documents (TF-IDF vectors).
Documents are sent through a Lucene English analyzer, and sparse vectors are created from HashingTF.transform() function.
Whatever the degree of parrallelism I'm using (through the coalesce function), KMeans.train always return an OutOfMemory exception below. Any thought on how to tackle this issue ?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at scala.reflect.ManifestFactory$$anon$12.newArray(Manifest.scala:138)
at scala.reflect.ManifestFactory$$anon$12.newArray(Manifest.scala:136)
at breeze.linalg.Vector$class.toArray(Vector.scala:80)
at breeze.linalg.SparseVector.toArray(SparseVector.scala:48)
at breeze.linalg.Vector$class.toDenseVector(Vector.scala:75)
at breeze.linalg.SparseVector.toDenseVector(SparseVector.scala:48)
at breeze.linalg.Vector$class.toDenseVector$mcD$sp(Vector.scala:74)
at breeze.linalg.SparseVector.toDenseVector$mcD$sp(SparseVector.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.BreezeVectorWithNorm.toDense(KMeans.scala:422)
at org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans$$anonfun$initKMeansParallel$1.apply(KMeans.scala:285)
at org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans$$anonfun$initKMeansParallel$1.apply(KMeans.scala:284)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans.initKMeansParallel(KMeans.scala:284)
at org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans.runBreeze(KMeans.scala:143)
at org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans.run(KMeans.scala:126)
at org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans$.train(KMeans.scala:338)
at org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans$.train(KMeans.scala:348)
```

Comment: Can you check whether the problem comes from the fact that there is no more memory or the vector tries to create a too large array (something close to Integer.MAX_VALUE for example)? Is this consistently from the newArray method?

Comment: It always come from the same newArray method. Using HashingTF, vectors are freaking large, but sparse. I wonder why MLLib tries to convert them into DenseVectors (That could be the issue)

Comment: According to this: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/clustering/KMeans.scala#L307 it seems your dimension is too large. Have you tried dimension reduction before? (Though that might require even more memory, I am not sure.)

Comment: I've noticed the same. Both initKMeansParallel and initRandom implementations create a Dense copy of my centers vector, hence causing the Out of memory error. I will look at the possible dimension reduction such as SVD. Thanks Gabor

Comment: Depending on your use case probably filtering out the least frequent words or keeping only the on-topic words might be a more cheap option, though SVD might give better (unbiased) results. See also: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24493/how-to-reduce-dimension-for-text-document-dataset

Comment: Dimension reduction did not solve the issue (see answer below) because of the nature of HashingTF vectors. I've manually built my TF-IDF sparse vectors, it works like a charm now. Cheers !

Comment: mind sharing your way of building the vectors for TF-IDF? I'm still running into the issue of OutOfMemory when using SparseVectors in KMeans.

```An error occurred while calling o379.trainKMeansModel.
: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector.toArray(Vectors.scala:523)
 at org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans$$anonfun$initRandom$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(KMeans.scala:267) ```

Answer (score 4):

After some investigations, it turns out that this issue was related to `new HashingTF().transform(v)` method. Although creating sparse vectors using hashing trick is really helpful (especially when the number of features is not known), vector **must** be kept sparse. Default size for HashingTF vectors is 2^20. Given a 64bits double precision, each vector would theoretically require 8MB when converted to Dense vector - regardless the dimension reduction we could apply.

Sadly, KMeans uses *toDense* method (at least for the cluster centers), therefore causing OutOfMemory error (imagine with k = 1000).

```
  private def initRandom(data: RDD[BreezeVectorWithNorm]) : Array[Array[BreezeVectorWithNorm]] = {
    val sample = data.takeSample(true, runs * k, new XORShiftRandom().nextInt()).toSeq
    Array.tabulate(runs)(r => sample.slice(r * k, (r + 1) * k).map { v =>
      new BreezeVectorWithNorm(v.vector.toDenseVector, v.norm)
    }.toArray)
  }
```