# How to use RowMatrix.columnSimilarities (similarity search)

Tags: scala, machine-learning, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

**TL;DR;** I am trying to train off of an existing data set (`Seq[Words]` with corresponding categories), and use that trained dataset to filter another dataset using category similarity.

I am trying to train a corpus of data and then use it for text analysis*. I've tried using `NaiveBayes`, but that seems to only work with the data you have, so it's predict algorithm will always return something, even if it doesn't match anything.

So, I am now trying to use TFIDF and passing that output into a RowMatrix and computing the similarities. But, I'm not sure how to run my query (one word for now). Here's what I've tried:

```
val rddOfTfidfFromCorpus : RDD[Vector]
val query = "word"
val tf = new HashingTF().transform(List(query))
val tfIDF = new IDF().fit(sc.makeRDD(List(tf))).transform(tf)  
val mergedVectors = rddOfTfidfFromCorpus.union(sc.makeRDD(List(tfIDF)))
val similarities = new RowMatrix(mergedVectors).columnSimilarities(1.0)
```

Here is where I'm stuck (if I've even done everything right until here). I tried filtering the `similarities` `i` and `j` down to the parts of my query's TFIDF and end up with an empty collection.

The gist is that I want to train on a corpus of data and find what category it falls in. The above code is at least trying to get it down to one category and checking if I can get a prediction from that at least....

*Note that this is a toy example, so I only need something that works well enough
*I am using Spark 1.4.0

Comment: @zero323 Corrected, thanks. And thanks for the edit on code....forgot to shift after I was done typing

Comment: You're welcome. So, could explain what exactly your are trying to do here? I cannot make any sense of your code :( Some kind of clustering? Similarity search?

Comment: Yes. Similarity search

Comment: I added a TLDR...sorry, ml is my weakest aspect of Spark....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `columnSimilarities` doesn't make sense here. Since each column in your matrix represents a set of terms you'll get a matrix of similarities between tokens not documents. You could transpose the matrix and then use `columnSimilarities` but as far as I understand what you want is a similarity between query and corpus. You can express that using matrix multiplication as follows:

For starters you'll need an `IDFModel` you've trained on a corpus. Lets assume it is called  `idf`:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.IDFModel
val idf: IDFModel = ??? // Trained using corpus data
```

and a small helper:

```
def toBlockMatrix(rdd: RDD[Vector]) = new IndexedRowMatrix(
  rdd.zipWithIndex.map{case (v, i) => IndexedRow(i, v)}
).toCoordinateMatrix.toBlockMatrix
```

First lets convert query to an RDD and compute TF:

```
val query: Seq[String] = ??? 
val queryTf = new HashingTF().transform(query)
```

Next we can apply IDF model and convert result to matrix:

```
val queryTfidf = idf.transform(queryTf)
val queryMatrix = toBlockMatrix(queryTfidf)
```

We'll need a corpus matrix as well:

```
val corpusMatrix = toBlockMatrix(rddOfTfidfFromCorpus)
```

If you multiple both we get a matrix with number of rows equal to the number of docs in the query and number of columns equal to the number of documents in the corpus.

```
val dotProducts = queryMatrix.multiply(corpusMatrix.transpose)
```

To get a proper cosine similarity you have to divide by a product of magnitudes but if you can handle that.

There are two problems here. First of all it is rather expensive. Moreover I am not sure if it really useful. To reduce cost you can apply some dimensionality reduction algorithm first but lets leave it for now.

Judging from a following statement

> NaiveBayes (...) seems to only work with the data you have, so it's predict algorithm will always return something, even if it doesn't match anything.

I guess you want some kind of unsupervised learning method. The simplest thing you can try is K-means:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.{KMeans, KMeansModel}

val numClusters: Int = ???
val numIterations = 20

val model = KMeans.train(rddOfTfidfFromCorpus, numClusters, numIterations)
val predictions = model.predict(queryTfidf)
```

Comment: Accepted as the answer...although I keep running into memory problems due to the size of each Vector. I may try using Word2Vec instead of TFIDF...my understanding is that will end up resulting in a smaller memory imprint

Comment: At Kmeans is where I'm oom

Comment: I think it's related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449446/apache-spark-mllib-running-kmeans-with-idf-tf-vectors-java-heap-space Any ideas on how I might be able to featurize my words without running out of memory?

Comment: I just collected my tfidf, it's ~75000 vectors taking up 5MB in the cache (deserialized)...and this is for a set of 54 wiki pages...not even the entire set

Comment: Do you perform any filtering steps before you create vectors? Stopwords removal? Rare terms removal? Stemming / lemmatization? If not it could be a good place to start. Depending on a number of terms after cleaning you could adjust `numFeatures` parameter.  Another thing you can try is PCA before applying K-means.

Comment: First, I got past my OOM as I never reset my features from the default(now using a more manageable number)...As far as removal, Yah I am indeed cleaning the words before hand....So, I now have my clusters, but it's telling me the same cluster center for everything....I'm assuming it has something to do with running a tfidf on a one word query...looking into it now

Comment: My current test corpus is only 54 wiki pages, but they range across a few categories....they really should result in my queries returning different centers...